# How to COUNT from 'Case When' Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I hope someone can help, about my case :

How to count from my case when condition in my sql code like this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3
THEN 'NOK'
ELSE 'OK'
END AS
STATUS FROM complaint a
LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid
```

[image]

Comment: `SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM complaint GROUP BY status` did you try this

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   CASE
        WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3 THEN 'NOK'
        ELSE 'OK'
   END AS STATUS 
FROM complaint a
LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid 
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3 THEN 'NOK'
            ELSE 'OK'
         END
```

Alternatively, You can turn the status(OK, NOK) into distinct columns:

```
SELECT   
   COUNT CASE WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3 THEN 1 END) AS 'NOK',
   COUNT CASE WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) <=3 THEN 1 END) AS  'OK' 
FROM complaint a LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

it just should be like this :D haha :

```
Select status,count(*)
From 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN datediff( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3 THEN 'NOK' ELSE 'OK' END AS STATUS FROM complaint a LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid
) a
Group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3 THEN 'NOK' ELSE 'OK' END AS mystatus, 
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF( b.`DATE` , A.`SUBMIT_DATE` ) >3,1,0)) AS cnt 
FROM complaint a
LEFT JOIN handling b ON a.cid = b.cid 
GROUP BY mystatus;
```